# Performance impact of rewriting WordPress URLs

Tags: php, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm currently rewriting author URLs in WordPress.

1. I've removed the author base slug `/author/`. Please note I have total control over page slugs so can guarantee there will be no conflicts.
2. I've added 3 endpoints (posts, comments, articles) so that author links can look like:

   example.com/username/posts

   example.com/username/comments

   example.com/username/articles

Will rewrite rules such as this have an impact on my website's performance? For theoretical sake let's say the number of authors were in the millions.

**References:**

Endpoints
https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/

Rewrite rules
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Answer (score 1):

From performance point of view what takes time is matching URL against generated (and stored persistently so it's not rebuilt continuously) list of regular expressions.

Since URLs are (most of the time) insignificantly short in text volume the amount of those regular expression rules has most impact on performance. Unless you generate unreasonably many rules. Which endpoints probably won't, although some things like (now fixed) category-based permalinks might.

In a nutshell — check that you `WP_Rewrite` rules aren't getting crazy large and (as always) if you are really concerned about performance than profile it.